# Powershell - Retrieving Calendar Items - specifically reoccurring meetings which the user has adjusted the duration

Tags: powershell, outlook, calendar

I have an existing powershell script (which hopefully i can link in full here below), which retrieves all calendar items for a given date range, and then tries to create summaries (our stupid company wants us to do timesheets, and i'm trying to make this slightly easier).

It works well so far as i can tell, however whilst it retrieves reoccurring meeting as well as normal ones, the reoccurring meetings have incorrect durations.

For example if somebody has gone in and adjusted a specific instance of a reoccurring meeting (i.e. you think the meeting is going to go for 2 hours, but it finishes early, so after the meeting you adjust it to 1.5 hours or something)... those entries seem to be retrieved as though they weren't adjusted at all.. if that makes sense? You just get the originally planned duration, instead of the time you adjusted the meeting to. Hopefully that makes sense?

Hoping somebody could help me to modify this code to take those adjusted instances of reoccurring meetings into account in the final output.

P.s. apologies in advance my powershell is... not great, and a decent portion of this is stolen from the internet somewhere.

```
# define working directory of the script based on powershell version that is hosting the script
if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 3){$WorkingDirectory = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition}
else{$WorkingDirectory = $PSScriptRoot}

$outfile = "$($workingDirectory)\output\Output.csv"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook'

function Get-WeekNumber([datetime]$DateTime = (Get-Date)) {
    $cultureInfo = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture
    $cultureInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear($DateTime,$cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,$cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
}
function Get-Iso8601WeekNumber([datetime]$DateTime = (Get-Date)) {
    # ISO8601: Week starts on Monday and Week 1 is the week that contains Thursday
    $calendar = [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture.Calendar
    $dow      = $calendar.GetDayOfWeek($DateTime)
    if ($dow -ge [DayOfWeek]::Monday -and $dow -le [DayOfWeek]::Wednesday) {
        $DateTime = $DateTime.AddDays(3)
    }
    return $calendar.GetWeekOfYear($DateTime, [Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFourDayWeek, [DayOfWeek]::Monday)
}
function Get-ISOWeek {
  Param(
        [Parameter(
            # Mandatory,
            ValueFromPipeline,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,
            HelpMessage = 'Valid Date'
        )]
        [Alias('DT', 'DateTime')]
            [datetime[]]$Dates = (Get-Date),
        [Validateset('Culture', 'UICulture', 'InvariantCulture')]
        [string]$Culture
    )
    <#
        First create an integer(0/1) from the boolean,
        "Is the integer DayOfWeek value greater than zero?".
        Then Multiply it with 4 or 6 (weekrule = 0 or 2) minus the integer DayOfWeek value.
        This turns every day (except Sunday) into Thursday.
        Then return the ISO8601 WeekNumber.
    #>
    BEGIN {
        $Cult = Switch ($Culture) {
            'UICulture' {
                Get-UICulture
                Break
            }
            'InvariantCulture' {
                [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
                Break
            }
            default{
                Get-Culture
            }
        }
        $WeekRule = $Cult.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule.value__
        $FirstDayOfWeek = $Cult.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek.value__
    }
    PROCESS{
        ForEach ($DateElement in $Dates) {
            Try {
                Write-Verbose "------------------------"
                Write-Verbose "Try to turn $DateElement into ISO8601Week"
                $WeekRuleDay = [int]($DateElement.DayOfWeek.Value__ -ge $FirstDayOfWeek ) * ( (6 - $WeekRule) - $DateElement.DayOfWeek.Value__ )
                $WeekNumber = $Cult.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(($DateElement).AddDays($WeekRuleDay), $WeekRule, $FirstDayOfWeek)
<#
I need to check the DayNumber formula. The FirstDayOfTheWeek must become 1
In the Netherlands we start with Monday
#>
                $DayNumber = (7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)[$($DateElement.DayOfWeek.value__ + 1)]
                $Properties = @{
                    Date = Get-Date($DateElement)
                    LongDate = Get-Date($DateElement).ToLongDateString()
                    WeekRuleDay = $WeekRuleDay
                    WeekNumber = $WeekNumber
          ISOWeek    = "$($DateElement.Year)-W$WeekNumber"
          ISOWeekDay = "$($DateElement.Year)-W$WeekNumber-$DayNumber"
          ISO8601Week    = "$($DateElement.Year)-W$WeekNumber"
                    ISO8601WeekDay = "$($DateElement.Year)-W$WeekNumber-$DayNumber"
                }
            } Catch {
                Write-Verbose "Could not turn: $DateElement into ISO8601Week"
                $Properties = @{
                    Date = $DateElement
                    LongDate = ''
                    WeekRuleDay = ''
                    WeekNumber = ''
          ISOWeek    = ''
          ISOWeekDay = ''
          ISO8601Week    = ''
                    ISO8601WeekDay = ''
                }
            } Finally{
                Write-Verbose "Final"
                $Obj = New-Object -Typename PSCustomObject -Property $Properties
                Write-Output $Obj
            }
            
        }
    }
    END{}
}

# example: (20..31).ForEach( { (Get-ISOWeek("2012-12-$($_)")).ISOWeekDay }) + ((1..7).ForEach( { (Get-ISOWeek("2013-1-$($_)")).ISOWeekDay })) -join ','

function Get-DatesInWeekNumber {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [int] $WeekNumber,
    [int] $Year = (Get-Date).Year,
    [DayOfWeek] $FirstDayOfWeek = 'Monday'
  )
  $date = [Globalization.ISOWeek]::ToDateTime($Year, $WeekNumber, $FirstDayOfWeek)
  0..6 | ForEach-Object { $date.AddDays($_) }
}


function CustomForm {
    param(
        [String] $Message = "Oh no, you didn't select a message"
    )
    $form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
    
    # used only to determine maximum number of days backwards you can select.
    $Today = [datetime]::today
    
    # the form itself
    $form.Text = $Message
    #$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(200,200)
    $form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(500,100)
    $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    #$Form.AutoSize = $False
    $Form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"

    # OK button
    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,25)
    $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $OKButton.Text = 'OK'
    $OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
    $form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
    $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

    # cancel button
    $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(80,25)
    $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
    $CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
    # add the cancel button to the form.
    $form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
    $form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

    # Asin, go to the front of all other open windows...
    $form.Topmost = $true

    # TimePicker
    $TimePicker = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
    $TimePicker.Location = "0, 0"
    $TimePicker.Width = "150"
    $TimePicker.Format = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom
    $TimePicker.MinDate = $Today.AddDays(-365)
    $TimePicker.MaxDate = [datetime]::now
    $TimePicker.CustomFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    $TimePicker.ShowUpDown = $false
    $TimePicker.Enabled = $true
    # add the time picker to the form
    $Form.Controls.Add($TimePicker)

    $result = $Form.ShowDialog()
       
    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $TimePicker.Value
    }
    else {return $False}
}

$StartDate  = CustomForm -Message 'Choose a Start Date, time will be corrected to 00:00:00'
$endDate    = CustomForm -Message 'Choose a End Date, time will be corrected to 23:59:59'

if ($StartDate -and $endDate) {

    $StartDate  = Get-Date $StartDate -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0
    $endDate    = Get-Date $endDate -hour 23 -minute 59 -second 59
    
    Write-host "Start Date ($($StartDate.DayOfWeek)): $StartDate"
    Write-host "End Date ($($endDate.DayOfWeek)): $endDate"
    
    $olFolderCalendar = 9
    $ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $ns = $ol.GetNamespace('MAPI')
    $Start = (Get-Date $StartDate).Date.ToShortDateString()
    $End = (Get-Date $EndDate).AddDays(1).Date.ToShortDateString()
    
    $Filter = "[MessageClass]='IPM.Appointment' AND [Start] >= '$Start' AND [End] < '$end'"
    $appointments = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderCalendar).Items
    $appointments.IncludeRecurrences = $true
    $appointments.Sort("[Start]")
    $FilteredItems = $appointments.Restrict($Filter)
    
    # My data
    
    $InitialResults = $FilteredItems | ForEach-Object {
        $duration = $Null
        $duration = $_.duration
        
        $categories = $Null
        $categories = $_.categories
        
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($duration)) {
            #do nothing
        } else {
            
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($categories) -or $Categories -eq '##Skip') {
                # you didn't categorize the calendar entry, so... it's not going into our results...or you categorized it to the standard "##Skip" value..
            } else {
                $timespan = $null
                $timespan = new-timespan -minutes $Duration
                
                $date = Get-date $_.Start
                
                $WeekNumber = $Null
                $WeekNumber = Get-WeekNumber $Date
                
                ## we probably don't care about this? especially now given the only culture reliable way i can retrieve is via pwsh7+
                #$datesinWeek = Get-DatesInWeekNumber -WeekNumber $WeekNumber # only works in powershell 7....
                #
                #$FirstDayofWeek = $DatesinWeek[0]
                #$LastDayofWeek = $DatesinWeek[6]
                
                ## below is NOT culture aware... (i.e. Monday may not be first day of week)
                ### Calculate the Monday of the week
                ##$Monday = ((Get-Date $Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddDays(-([int]$Date.DayOfWeek - [int][System.DayOfWeek]::Monday))).ToShortDateString()
                ##
                ### Output the Monday as a short date string
                ##$Sunday = ((Get-date $date -hour 23 -minute 59 -second 59).AddDays(7-([int]$Date.DayOfWeek - [int][System.DayOfWeek]::Sunday))).ToShortDateString()

                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Categories              =   $categories
                    DurationInMins          =   $duration
                    DurationInHours         =   $timespan | Select -expand TotalHours
                    WeekDay                 =   $Date | Select -expand DayofWeek
                    WeekofYear              =   "Week $WeekNumber"  # "Week $(Get-date $Date -uformat %V)" <- not culture aware..
                    #FirstDayofWeek         =   $FirstDayofWeek         # probably don't care about this information...so.. too hard basket...
                    #LastDayofWeek          =   $LastDayofWeek          # probably don't care about this information...so.. too hard basket...
                    Date                    =   $_.Start.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                    IsRecurring             =   $_.IsRecurring
                    Subject                 =   $_.Subject
                    Start                   =   $_.Start
                    'End'                   =   $_.'End'
                }
            }
        }

    }
    
    # add total hours worked for each day...
    $PerDayTotal                    =   $InitialResults | Group-Object 'WeekDay','Date'                 | Select-Object 'Name', @{n='PerDayTotal'               ;e={($_.Group | Measure-Object 'DurationInHours' -Sum).Sum}}
    $PerWeekTotal                   =   $InitialResults | Group-Object 'WeekofYear'                     | Select-Object 'Name', @{n='PerWeekTotal'              ;e={($_.Group | Measure-Object 'DurationInHours' -Sum).Sum}}
    $PerCategoryPerDayTotal         =   $InitialResults | Group-Object 'WeekDay', 'Date', 'Categories'  | Select-Object 'Name', @{n='PerCategoryPerDayTotal'    ;e={($_.Group | Measure-Object 'DurationInHours' -Sum).Sum}}
    $PerCategoryPerWeekTotal        =   $InitialResults | Group-Object 'WeekofYear', 'Categories'       | Select-Object 'Name', @{n='PerCategoryPerWeekTotal'   ;e={($_.Group | Measure-Object 'DurationInHours' -Sum).Sum}}
    
    
    $Finalresult = foreach ($result in $InitialResults) {
        
        $result | Select `
        @{n='PerDayTotal'               ;E={$PerDayTotal                | ? {$_.Name -like "*$($result.Date)*"}                                                     | Select -expand PerDayTotal}},
        @{n='PerWeekTotal'              ;E={$PerWeekTotal               | ? {$_.Name -eq $result.WeekofYear}                                                        | Select -expand PerWeekTotal}},
        @{n='PerCategoryPerDayTotal'    ;E={$PerCategoryPerDayTotal     | ? {$_.Name -like "*$($result.Date)*" -and $_.Name -like "*$($result.Categories)*"}        | Select -expand PerCategoryPerDayTotal}},
        @{n='PerCategoryPerWeekTotal'   ;E={$PerCategoryPerWeekTotal    | ? {$_.Name -like "*$($result.WeekofYear)*" -and $_.Name -like "*$($result.Categories)*"}  | Select -expand PerCategoryPerWeekTotal}},
        *
    }

    if ($Finalresult) {
        $Finalresult | Sort WeekofYear, WeekDay, PerCategoryPerWeekTotal, Categories | Export-csv $outfile -nti
        $Finalresult | Sort WeekofYear, WeekDay, PerCategoryPerWeekTotal, Categories | Out-gridview -wait -title "This data has been written to: $outfile"
    }
    
    Write-host "Totals per Day" -fore black -back Yellow
    $PerDayTotal | ft -autosize
    
    Write-host "Totals per Week" -fore black -back Yellow   
    $PerWeekTotal | ft -autosize
    
    Write-host "Totals per Category, Per Day" -fore black -back Yellow  
    $PerCategoryPerDayTotal | ft -autosize
    
    Write-host "Totals per Category, Per Week" -fore black -back Yellow 
    $PerCategoryPerWeekTotal | ft -autosize
}
```

Comment: If it helps anyone, I realised i was basing a lot on the "duration" property of the meeting... which, in that particular scenario seems to be incorrect...all i've done is change the code to use another new-Timespan on the start and end times instead (which seem to be accurate).